# Haskell Nested Loop accumulator

Tags: haskell, loops, functional-programming, accumulator

I'm working on modifying my server side programming language from PHP to Haskell and am therefore not fully acquainted with functional language design.

Here I want to convert part of the processing code of something like the following php function to Haskell:

```
function loop($A) {
  $array1 = array();
  $num = (int)$A;
  if ($num == 0)
    $array1 = "0";
  for (int $i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
    foreach (loop($i-$num) as &$value)
      $array1[] = "+ ".$value." ";  //concat
  return $array1;
}
```

I imagine there would be heavy use of the map/mapM_ functions, but how would the accumulation work? I'm starting to think that the added safety won't be worth the transformation at this point.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your php code. Where does `$loop` come from? Where is `$num` used?

Comment: sorry, $num is used to make sure $A is an int. $loop is meant to be loop.

Comment: But the way you're using $loop suggests it's an array of arrays. Did you mean $loop(2*$i) and $loop(2*$i-1)? Doesn't nesting all these foreach statements mean you print every single combination of key and value? Shouldn't you have passed $loop as a parameter? If your code above works, you'll need to explain how. If not, can you explain with example data what you want as output? Also if not, I think the type safety will help you write better code, but it will take time to learn.

Comment: So it's a recursive call? Actually, it looks like you overwrite $array1[] every time, so only the last pair ever gets described. Did you mean $array1[$i] or something?

Comment: I think you need to explain what the code is designed to do, with input and output.

Comment: @TimH Your current code seems to recurse forever back towards negative infinity. Even if you replace `$i=0` wtih `$i=1` to avoid that, it goes into an infinite loop. I don't think your php code works, and I think a decription of the task in words and examples is the only way we can understand what you're trying to compute. Gabriel Gonzalez has given a good answer based on an assumption about what you were trying to achieve. Is it right? Please give some feedback on that answer. If not, please explain your code's purpose.

Comment: AndrewC, you are right in that the code loops forever. Now it shouldn't with the $i-$A modification. My hope was of understanding how a function like this is implemented in Haskell without using the temporary storage of $i, and $array1[] like in php. In that sense the use is not important and perhaps I should give a simpler function to help get the point out.

Comment: @TimHaggard I've translated your code as it currently stands to Haskell. It's never going to achieve anything useful just now, but at least I can translate it.

Comment: Agreed with AndrewC.  Give some examples of input and expected output.  If you phrased it along the lines of (for example--I've got no idea what your code does) [0,2,3] begets "22333", I'd be more inclined to investigate.  As is, I know nothing about PHP, and it's not at all evident what you're trying to do, so I'm moving on to someone else's question, and likely so are many others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the php as it stands at the time I'm answering:

```
function loop($A) {
  $array1 = array();
  $num = (int)$A;
  if ($num == 0)
    $array1 = "0";
  for (int $i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
    foreach (loop($i-$num) as &$value)
      $array1[] = "+ ".$value." ";  //concat
  return $array1;
}
```

A literal translation of the above code into Haskell would be:

```
loop :: Int -> [String]
loop 0 = ["0"]
loop num = ["+ " ++ value ++ " " | i <- [0..num], value <- loop (i - num)]
```

It still doesn't achieve anything, but it does give you the flavour of 
Haskell's "loop"ing or iteration in list comprehensions.

First thing to notice is that the type signature `loop :: Int -> [String]` immediately 
alerted me to write `loop 0 = ["0"]` instead of `loop 0 = "0"` which would be more literally
what you had, but Haskell has spotted that the output of loop would be inconsistent if it
were sometimes a list of Strings and sometimes just a String. I think it's this kind of error 
checking it's worth learning about - maybe all the code you wrote when revising would compile in php,
but because of the design inconsistencies, Haskell *won't* - it forces you to think clearly at writing time
and fix bugs before compile time.

I'll explain my code, not as a full explanation of Haskell, but as a taster and relating it to your code:

```
loop :: Int -> [String]
```

`loop` is a function that takes an `Int`eger and returns a list of Strings. 
Haskell won't let you use this with any other data type now, which means it's type safe, and you're protected
from all sorts of nasty bugs straight out of the box. The type system is actually very flexible, expressive 
and powerful, and is one of the reasons we love Haskell, but here I'm using it to lock the function down.

(Lists are used widely in Haskell instead of arrays. They're *very* convenient and work fast for sequential access.
There are array data types but they're less lovely/Haskellish - get used to lists first.)

```
loop 0 = ["0"]
```

This means if you call `loop` with the Int `0`, it should return the list with one string, "0".

```
loop num = [ something | stuff... ]
```

Means you can get the values of your variables inside `stuff` and return them in `something`, so

```
loop num = [ "+ " ++ value ++ " " | stuff... ]
```

means we'll return (Haskell's version of) `"+ ".$value." "`. Here we use `++` instead of php's `.`.

```
i <- [0..num]
```

This means let `i` range from `0` to `num`. It has to be an `Int` because `num` is because `loop :: Int -> ...`.

```
value <- loop (i - num)
```

This means let `value` range across the result of calling `loop` with the number `i - num`. 
`value` has to bee a `String` because `loop :: Int -> [String]`.

In Haskell, it's like recursive calls are implemented as expression rewrites, 
so they disappear as they're called and don't clutter up the stack 
unless your calculation inherently clutters up the stack.

Putting it together gives:

```
loop num = ["+ " ++ value ++ " " | i <- [0..num], value <- loop (i - num)]
```

If that notation feels very weird, you might be more comfortable with more imperative style syntax:

```
loop :: Int -> [String]
loop 0 = ["0"]
loop num = do
    i <- [0..num]
    value <- loop (i - num)
    return ("+ " ++ value ++ " ")
```

Of course it *still* doesn't do anything useful but at least it's easy to keep track of.

Why not work through *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good* at http://learnyouahaskell.com/ or *Real World Haskell* at http://book.realworldhaskell.org/ both tutorials that start simple but go deep. I think you'll find Haskell a great way to write a small amount of correct code to replace a large amount of OK code. Think more clearly, write less!

Comment: @TimHaggard I don't have any variable corresponding to `$array1` in my code because your `$array1` is just used to store the result before returning it. In Haskell we just return it, no need for another variable. Also, I didn't need seperate variables for your `$A` and `$num` becasue I used the type signature `loop :: Int -> [String]` to typecheck instead of a cast. (If I'd wanted to use a variable called `A`, I can't, variables can only start with a lowercase letter. Initial Capital is for types and constructors.)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have some sort of dictionary.  The typical Haskell data structure for a dictionary is a `Map`, provided by `Data.Map`.  So if your keys are `String`s and your values are `Int`s, then your Map would have type `Map String Int`.

Now, judging by your code, it seems you mix your keys and values in the same array, so first we have to separate them into key value pairs.  I will pretend your starting input is a list instead of an array, although everything I'm writing here works perfectly fine for Haskell arrays, too:

```
fix :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
fix [] = []
fix [_] = []
fix (k:v:xs) = (k, v):fix xs
```

You can choose to stop there at an association list, in which case you could transform it into a list of descriptive strings:

```
describe :: (Show k, Show v) => [(k, v)] -> [String]
describe xs = map (\(k, v) -> "Stored On: " ++ show k ++ ", item: " ++ show v) xs
```

Or we could print them out directly:

```
printPairs :: (Show k, Show v) => [(k, v)] -> IO ()
printPairs xs = mapM_ putStrLn (describe xs)
```

Now, for more efficient lookups, you typically want to store the association list as a `Map`, so all you would use is the `fromList` function in `Data.Map`:

```
fromList :: Ord k => [(k, v)] -> Map k v
```

And any time you want to take the list back out of the map (i.e. to print it), you just use `toList`:

```
toList :: Map k v -> [(k, v)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. There is no dictionary here, just the function loop() which returns an array of strings. I was hoping to see how we can deal with the PHP temporary variables $i, and $array1[].